# visual studio suddenly doesn't recognize anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a WinForms project on Visual Studio Community 2013. I pressed F6+(something) (mistakenly) and suddenly Visual Studio doesn't recognize what is bool, void, class, checkBox and I got like 40 errors (mainly on the check box). I tried to check all my files, but I can't see the cause.

Comment: restart Visual Studio

Comment: tried that, didn't work. I even tried opening a new project and copying all the files but didn't work.

Comment: clear your solution and rebuild,

Comment: What are the sort of errors you're getting?  Is it the same error repeated for lots of different files?

Comment: Try to reset settings from Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings -> C#

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. The errors are: Invalid token 'if',invalid token '(', invalid token '=',expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct. it's like he doesn't know what 'if' is.

Comment: Check your Error List for any message like "Expected { "  or "Expected ;". Perhaps you removed something accidentally. Also, if you didn't yet restart VS try Ctrl+Z to revert your changes. Maybe that will bring you back to the state from before the error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a } or deleting a { in some places in your code can have this effect.